# Does storage reuse really require object destruction?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, storage, object-lifetime, placement-new

According to [[basic.life/1]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic#life-1) (bold emphasis mine):

> The **lifetime** of an object of type T **begins when:**
>
> - **storage** with the proper alignment and size for type T **is obtained, and**
> - its **initialization** (if any) **is complete** (including vacuous initialization) ([dcl.init]),
>   except that if the object is a union member or subobject thereof, its lifetime only begins if that union member is the initialized member in the union ([dcl.init.aggr], [class.base.init]), or as described in [class.union] and [class.copy.ctor], and except as described in [allocator.members].
>
> The **lifetime** of an object o of type T **ends when:**
>
> - if T is a non-class type, the object is destroyed, or
> - if T is a class type, the **destructor call starts, or**
> - the **storage** which the object occupies **is released, or is reused** by an object that is not nested within o ([intro.object]).

So we have:

```
|------------|----|--------------|----------|-------------|----|--------------|

 <---------->      <------------> <--------> <----------->      <------------>
  storage           object         object     object             storage
  allocation        construction   lifetime   destruction        deallocation

              <----------------------------------------------->
               storage duration
```

According to [[basic.life/8]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic#life-8) (bold emphasis mine):

> **If, after the lifetime of an object has ended and before the storage which the object occupied is reused or released, a new object is created at the storage location which the original object occupied,** a pointer that pointed to the original object, a reference that referred to the original object, or the name of the original object will automatically refer to the new object and, once the lifetime of the new object has started, can be used to manipulate the new object, if the original object is transparently replaceable (see below) by the new object.

Two questions come to mind:

1. Is the placement `new` operator the only means to reuse storage?
2. Does the consequence specified in [basic.life/8] really require the original object to be destroyed (i.e. the condition ‘after the lifetime of an object has ended’)?

Comment: 2. It does, but should not, because this requirement makes the unions unusable in C++ (if a union member was not originally active, it is not possible to make it active, since creating an object of member's type won't make the member's name refer to the new [sub]object)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Do you mean it makes the statement `name.~basic_string();` required in the member assignment operator in the code of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69159423/2326961)?

Comment: @Maggyero: That's required because you *need* to destroy the object, since it is a non-trivial destructor that your code is relying on being called to free up memory.

Comment: No, object's lifetime ends just from storage reuse. This is enough for [basic.life]/8. Mebby my first comment is confusing. Explicit destructor call is not required, but neither lifetime end should be.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer About 2, okay so we agree that the condition ‘after the lifetime of an object has ended’ should be removed from the standard because the lifetime of the orignal object will end anyway from storage reuse.

Comment: No, it should be removed because sometimes lifetime of the old object doesn't even start (so it can't be ended), but a name needa be rebound to the new object.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Let’s clarify: A. [basic.life/1] specifies that storage reuse, storage release, or object destruction ends an object’s lifetime. B. [basic.life]/8 specifies that if an object’s lifetime ends *before* storage reuse or storage release, storage can be reused for a new object. Therefore from A and B, if an object is destroyed *before* storage reuse or storage release, storage can be reused for a new object. Now I think there are two problems with this statement: 1. This does not make sense: ‘*before* storage reuse’. 2. This is unnecessary: ‘if an object is destroyed’. Do you agree?

Comment: See https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.life#11 what «before» and «after» mean and what they are needed for.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer The problem is not the meaning of before, it is: before storage reuse, storage can be reused. It implies that storage can only be reused once, which is insane.

Comment: _It implies that storage can only be reused once_ I don't see this.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Basically it says: *if you create an object in storage where an object whose lifetime ended and the storage hasn’t been reused/released, then…* But why doesn’t it just say: *if you create an object in storage where the storage hasn’t been released, then…* In other words, wouldn’t the consequence on pointers/references/names referring to the object still apply with this less strict condition?

Comment: `int i; auto t1 = std::thread([&] { new (&i) int{1}; }), t2 = std::thread([&] { new (&i) int{2}; }); t1.join(); t2.join();` which object does `i` denote now?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer There is a race condition so I don’t know. What did you want to show?

Comment: What is «race condition»? If you mean «data race», there is none in the code fragment.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I mean that both threads are updating the same storage location concurrently.

Comment: What is «storage location»? If you mean «memory location», they are not the same. (And I'd say there are no updates)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I don’t know the difference. Yes the two threads are not ‘updating’ the value of an object at a storage location, they are ‘creating’ two objects at a storage location. But what point did you want to make with this example?

Answer (score 0):

As you quoted, if you reuse storage for a new object, the old object(s) in that storage have their lifetimes ended (unless the new object is nested within the old one). So if you create a new object inside storage containing an existing object(s), then the existing object(s) won't exist anymore.

> Is the placement `new` operator the only means to reuse storage?

The word "reuse" is not a term of art; it's just English. Anything that creates an object in storage will "reuse" the storage. For example, `construct_at` can reuse storage too.

Comment: `construct_at` is basically just a wrapper around placement new: http://eel.is/c++draft/specialized.construct#2.

Comment: All the ways how a new object may be created are here: http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#1.sentence-2.

Comment: About 2, so do you agree that the condition ‘after the lifetime of an object has ended’ should be removed from the standard because the lifetime of the orignal object will end anyway from storage reuse?

Comment: About 1, what C++ constructs currently allow storage reuse besides placement `new` and `construct_at`?

Comment: @Maggyero: "*do you agree that the condition ‘after the lifetime of an object has ended’ should be removed from the standard because the lifetime of the orignal object will end anyway from storage reuse?*" No, because it's talking specifically about a pointer/reference to, or the name of, a specific object. Noting that this object's lifetime has ended is part of that.

Comment: I am not sure I understand: since reusing an object’s storage ends its lifetime, why forcing the programmer to destroy it before storage reuse?

Comment: @Maggyero: You're misreading the text. It's not saying "to have effect Y, you must do X". It's saying "when X happens, then Y happens." Nobody is *forced* to do anything; this just explains what happens when these events take place.

Comment: Let’s clarify: A. [basic.life/1] specifies that storage reuse, storage release, or object destruction ends an object’s lifetime. B. [basic.life]/8 specifies that if an object’s lifetime ends *before* storage reuse or storage release, storage can be reused for a new object. Therefore from A and B, if an object is destroyed *before* storage reuse or storage release, storage can be reused for a new object. Now I think there are two problems with this statement: 1. ‘before storage reuse’ implies that storage can only be reused once. 2. ‘if an object is destroyed’ is unnecessary. Do you agree?

Comment: @Maggyero: "*if an object’s lifetime ends before storage reuse or storage release, storage can be reused for a new object.*" No, that is *not* what it says. Notice the comma after the first "If" in the paragraph. The comma-delineated section is a separate conditional. That is, it says "if you do this thing" (create an object) "in storage where this other thing is true" (an object whose lifetime ended and the storage hasn't been reused/released), then ...

Comment: @Maggyero: This is not *defining* what it means to "reuse storage". It's simply laying out what happens to pointers/references/names to an old object relative to a new object under certain conditions.

Comment: Yes it says: *if you create an object in storage where an object whose lifetime ended and the storage hasn’t been reused/released, then…* But why doesn’t it just say: *if you create an object in storage where the storage hasn’t been released, then…* In other words, wouldn’t the consequence on pointers/references/names referring to the object still apply with this less strict condition?